# Is it possible to save driving directions in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps to plan a road trip. One of the issues I have is that I would like to create a set of (maps? directions?), one for each day.

A daily trip would start at an address (a hotel) and end at another one (another hotel), with a customized route in between. I would like to have *n* such maps for the *n* days I will be travelling.

**Is this something possible to do with Google Maps?**

- I know about MyMaps, which allows to **save** a given route, but not **reuse** it as directions (in other words, I cannot use it as a GPS when driving, with normal directions indications I get in Google Maps).
- I know I can save the URL of a route, but this is not a "standalone" map (I will use this as last resort, but I will not easily have access to Internet when travelling and opening the URL requires Internet access)
- I could ultimately send an itinerary from the web based map to my phone, and save it on the home screen (the only way to save I found), but what is sent does not take into account the modified route (points dragged from the suggested route and dropped to the ones I want to go though)

Comment: why not just download region of the map where you travel for offline directions and then use GPS only with no internet (?) < that's how it should be done

Comment: @user0: because the route which will be suggested is the optimal one and mobile devices do not allow for a road customized by dragging the router. I can add waypoints but this is really cumbersome - as opposed to the web version where I can easily experiment with routes. As a side note: I will have the region offline in any case.